# ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive client validation with multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The ThingController creates a model which contains (amongst other properties) a collection of Things.  These can be edited in the view like so:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Update", "Thing")" method="post">        
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
        </tr>        
            @foreach (var thing in ViewData.Model.Things)
            {                
                <tr class="raw-data">
                    <td class="raw-data"><input name="things[@rowCount].Foo" class="raw-data" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="@thing.Foo" /></td>
                    <td class="raw-data"><input name="things[@rowCount].Bar" class="raw-data" type="text" value="@thing.Bar" /></td>
                </tr>                
                rowCount++;
            }
    </table>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />      
</form>
```

The controller contains the following action, which allows multiple Things to be updated simultaneously:

```
public ActionResult Update(ThingModel[] things)
{
  ...
}
```

I've added some validation attributes to properties on the Thing class:

```
[Required]
[Range(0, 500000, ErrorMessage = "Foo must be within 0 and 500,000.")]
public double Foo{ get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(0, 500000, ErrorMessage = "Bar must be within 0 and 500,000.")]
public double Bar { get; set; }
```

The thing is, I can't figure out how to add unobtrusive validation using the TextBoxFor  helpers etc.

At this point I think the correct approach is to manually mark up the input fields with the validation attributes, but I was wondering if anyone can point me to some documentation, a tutorial etc. that demonstrates the use of helpers, multiple models *and* unobtrusive validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem where users could dynamically add multiple emails to their account.
I fixed it with Jquery by adding the validation manually. You should give your form a name and add the validation to all your items. It should be something like this I quess:

```
    $('#frmYourForm').validate();
    for (var i = 0; i < 'CountOfAllFields'; i++) {
        $('#Things_' + i + '__Foo').rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: 'The Foo field is required'} });
        $('#Things_' + i + '__Bar').rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: 'The Bar field is required'} });
    }
```

Typed from my memory so don't shoot me if I made an error. I don't know the exact syntax for the Range thingy but you should look around the Jquery.validate file.